# If beef is banned in Tamil Nadu, India, how come there's beef on the menu?

Tags: india, legal, food-and-drink, restaurants, tamil-nadu

When I search Google, most results indicate that beef, as well as slaughtering cows, is illegal in Tamil Nadu, India.

However, I'm in Chennai right now and I'm seeing beef on the menu.

[image]

What's going on here? Is the information I found wrong, or is this some sort of buffalo vs. cow thing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per [this report](https://web.archive.org/web/20131029185034/http://www.dahd.nic.in/dahd/reports/report-of-the-national-commission-on-cattle/chapter-ii-executive-summary/annex-ii-8.aspx) (2013) from the National Commission on Cattle, while Tamil Nadu has strict controls on when cattle slaughter is allowed (basically, only sick or old animals), there is no ban per se on eating beef.

Comment: Also, Beef is very popular dish for Kerala, the neighboring state. So, its very likely that you will get beef (even if its not marked as such) everywhere with significant Keralite population. :)

Comment: I have seen things marked as "Meat curry", "Meat biriyani" such. Its most likely beef.

Comment: On TV someone explained that cows are not eaten but bulls are. Someone else in a different program said that waterbuffalo is often used instead of beef (but it should be mentioned on the menu if so.)

Comment: So basically it's only illegal to slaughter it locally, not to import already slaughtered meat from the neighboring province?

Comment: @vsz Not sure, but the report linked above does not mention imports.

Comment: @lambshaanxy : is it even officially considered an "import" if it's from within the same country, just a different region/state/provice?

Comment: @vsz Yes, not too long ago there were customs inspections at Indian state borders even for personal cars etc.